# How to append querystring in url using objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

NSString *post = @"&username=adam&password=test";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ws.myurl.com/svc-public/iPhoneAuthenticate.aspx?uname=adam&pword=test"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(response);
```

This is my url http://ws.myurl.com/svc-public/iPhoneAuthenticate.aspx, now I need to append the username and password dynamically.

How to append querystring in url? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.myurl.com/svc-public/iPhoneAuthenticate.aspx?uname=%@&pword=%@",name, password]]];
```

Comment: Of course you'd want to encode your username and password before passing outside your app...

Comment: Yes, sure. But that's another question